# how do you read the values of ALL items in a listbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, listbox

I have a listbox, and I want to read all of the items in a listbox using jquery.  I also would like to be able to identify for each item if it is selected or not.  What is the simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.myListBox option').each(function(index) {
  if ( ($(this).is(':selected')) {
    // do stuff if selected
  }
  else {
   // this one isn't selected, do other stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: Instead of `$(this).is(':selected')` you can simply use `this.selected`.

Answer (score 1):

Without any other information on how you want the output formatted:

```
$('#selectId').find('option').map(function() {
    return $(this).val() + ':' + $(this).is(':selected');
});
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/wpTs8/)